# How to use a VM to create a Rails staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, virtual-machine, staging, parallels

My app is in development and I do all my testing using WEBrick (I like the terminal output).

On the production server it will run on Phusion Passenger.

I'm running Snow Leopard and wish to test the app in an environment similar to the production environment.

Can I use Parallels to run a Debian install with Apache and Passenger and configure Capistrano to deploy to that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using VMware for that sort of thing. Its really easy to deal with network wise. I have recently switched to [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) which is much nicer to actually work in (at least for me), does the same things, and is free. Download the Debian iso and create a new VM that uses it as its CDrom. Thats about all you need to do. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you're looking for but I've found it very straightforward to just run passenger locally for development. You can always tail the development.log, it's really just as easy as watching the terminal output from webrick.

Dev setup is made all the easier with the drag and drop ease of the phusion passenger pref pane.

http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane

Seems like it would be easier than setting up the VM and all. Though yes, there could still be differences if your not hosting on OS X server I suppose.